# Images not show in sequence in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to show images from `XML enclosure` to tableViewCell image. Images are show but not in sequence, due to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` because when i scroll tableViewCell up and down it change images and not show in sequence according to `array index`. I've tried different ways but did't get success'
Can anyone please tell me how can show images in sequence, or is there any way that first download all images and then show in cell image??
Or any other quick or easy method instead using `dispatch_async`.
Thanks

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : ImageCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell2

        cell.titleLabel.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String

        downloadFileFromURL(NSURL(string: self.posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("enclosure") as! String)!, completionHandler:{(img) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                cell.sideImageView.image = img

                })
            })

        return cell

    }
```

> **UPDATE**

Now i tried this

```
let picURL = self.posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("enclosure") as! String
let url = NSURL(string: picURL)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

cell.sideImageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

It show images in sequence but make scrolling hard?

> **Update2**

Now i've tried this

```
var check = true
var imageArrayNsData : [NSData] = []

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell : ImageCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell2

cell.titleLabel.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String

if check == true{
            var indeX = 0
            for i in posts.valueForKey("enclosure") as! [NSString]{
                let picURL = self.posts.objectAtIndex(indeX).valueForKey("enclosure") as! String
                let url = NSURL(string: picURL)
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
                print("download")
                imageArrayNsData.append(data!)
                indeX++
                print(indeX)
            }
            check = false
        }

if check == false{
        cell.sideImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageArrayNsData[indexPath.row])
    }
return cell

}
```

This method only download images one time. And after downloading images it appends in array and next time it show images from array without downloading again. But this method is little bit hard for scrolling. Any one have idea why?

Comment: Are you redownloading the images every time you scroll or caching them? If you are redownloading then the old image from the reused cell will show until the new one has been loaded.

Comment: Yes it redownloading the images when i scroll it and it also show old images until the new one has been loaded. But every time it display images not in sequence?

Comment: Don't use contentsOfURL, it's a synchronous method and blocks the main thread. Downloads should be done in the background so they don't interfere with the UI.

Comment: Thanks but  if i use `AlamofireImage` it takes more storage memory. I've tried another method it works good but little bit make scrolling hard. Please check `UPDATE2`. Have you any idea how i make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `cell` object may have been already reused by the time you set the image. You need to add a check to make sure the cell still represents the content you want. That could be as simple as:

```
if tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) == indexPath {
    cell.sideImageView.image = img
}
```

But might need to be more complex if the index path for a specific item might change in that time (for example, if the user can insert/delete rows).

You could also use a library like [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) which handles this work (in a different way) for you. With AlamofireImage, your code would look like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : ImageCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell2            
    cell.titleLabel.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String

    let URL = NSURL(string: self.posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("enclosure") as! String)!
    cell.sideImageView.af_setImageWithURL(URL)

    return cell            
}
```

Comment: On a side note, you'll be a lot happier if you stop fighting the type system and serialize your data into model objects before you get to the table view

Comment: Thanks,  i've check `AlamofireImage` but if i use `AlamofireImage` it takes more storage memory on my app that i didn't want. I've tried another method it works good but little bit make scrolling hard. Please check `UPDATE2`. Have you any idea how i make it faster?

Comment: @ZAFAR007 Your new method will make scrolling not work while the image is being downloaded.

Comment: I know but I did't want to use AlamofireImage because it takes more storage due to its library files. Yes first i download images and saved them in NSData array then images are shows from array? Have you any idea i want to show placeholders until images are downloads on backend with my method and then these replace with placholders ? Thanks Aaron Barger

Comment: You don't need to use AlamofireImage if you don't want, but you can't download the images on the main thread either. You have to do it asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

To download asynchronously images and set to UIImageView of your UITableViewCell, you can add an extension to your UIImageView.

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImageFrom(link link:String, contentMode: UIViewContentMode) {
        //in my methods, I have a cache to avoid re-downloading my images. Images in cache are identified by its URL
        if let _imageData = ImageCache.shareCache.getImageData(link) {
            self.image = UIImage(data: _imageData)
            return
        }

        //else, download image
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL( NSURL(string:link)!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.contentMode =  contentMode
                if let data = data {
                    ImageCache.shareCache.cacheImageData(data, imageId: link)
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

then, from your call-back `cellforrow`,

```
let cell : ImageCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell2

cell.titleLabel.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String

cell.imageView.downloadImageFrom(yourImageUrl)
return cell
```

Comment: don't just copy/paste the answer. the ImageCache is for my application, remove it in your program.